# Is there a way to get the Apache Commons FileAlterationMonitor to only alert once for a batch of incoming files?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am monitoring several (about 15) paths for incoming files using the Apache Commons FileAlterationMonitor. These incoming files can come in batches of anywhere between 1 and 500 files at a time. I have everything set up and the application monitors the folders as expected, I have it set to poll the folders every minute. My issue is that, as expected, the listener that I have set up alerts for each incoming file when all I really need, and want, is to know when a new batch of files come in. So I would like to receive a single alert as opposed to up to 500 at a time.

Does anyone have any ideas for how to control the number of alerts or only pick up the first or last notification or something to that effect? I would like to stick with the FileAlterationMonitor if at all possible because it will be running for long periods and so far from what I can tell in testing is that it doesn't seem to put a heavy load on the system or slow the rest of the application down. But I am definitely open to other ideas if what I'm looking for isn't possible with the FileAlterationMonitor.

```
public class FileMonitor{

    private final String newDirectory;
    private FileAlterationMonitor monitor;
    private final Alerts gui;
    private final String provider;

    public FileMonitor (String d, Alerts g, String pro) throws Exception{
        newDirectory = d;
        gui = g;
        provider = pro;
    }


    public void startMonitor() throws Exception{

        // Directory to monitor
        final File directory = new File(newDirectory);

        // create new observer
        FileAlterationObserver fao = new FileAlterationObserver(directory);
        // add listener to observer
        fao.addListener(new FileAlterationListenerImpl(gui, provider));

        // wait 1 minute between folder polls. 
        monitor = new FileAlterationMonitor(60000);
        monitor.addObserver(fao);
        monitor.start();
    }
}

public class FileAlterationListenerImpl implements FileAlterationListener{

    private final Alerts gui;
    private final String provider;
    private final LogFiles monitorLogs;

    public FileAlterationListenerImpl(Alerts g, String pro){
        gui = g;
        provider = pro;
        monitorLogs = new LogFiles();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(final FileAlterationObserver observer){
        System.out.println("The FileListener has started on: " + observer.getDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDirectoryCreate(File file) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDirectoryChange(File file) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDirectoryDelete(File file) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFileCreate(File file) {
        try{
            switch (provider){
                case "Spectrum": gui.alertsAreaAppend("New/Updated schedules available for Spectrum zones!\r\n");
                             monitorLogs.appendNewLogging("New/Updated schedules available for Spectrum zones!\r\n");
                             break;
                case "DirecTV ZTA": gui.alertsAreaAppend("New/Updated schedules available for DirecTV ZTA zones!\r\n");
                                monitorLogs.appendNewLogging("New/Updated schedules available for DirecTV ZTA zones!\r\n");
                                break;
                case "DirecTV RSN": gui.alertsAreaAppend("New/Updated schedules available for DirecTV RSN zones!\r\n");
                                monitorLogs.appendNewLogging("New/Updated schedules available for DirecTV RSN zones!\r\n");
                                break; 
                case "Suddenlink": gui.alertsAreaAppend("New/Updated schedules available for Suddenlink zones!\r\n");
                               monitorLogs.appendNewLogging("New/Updated schedules available for Suddenlink zones!\r\n");
                                break;
            }
        }catch (IOException e){}
    }

    @Override
    public void onFileChange(File file) {
    }
```

Above is the FileMonitor class and overridden FileAlterationListener I have so far.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dont have much knowledge about `FileAlterationListener` but I quickly did some testing. Suppose you have folder A which will receive batch files. Instead of observing A if you observer the parent of A, lets call this B, then you'll get one`onDirectoryChange` event on B for all those 500 `onFileCreate` events in A.
But you'll have to move you `onFileCreate` imp to `onDirectoryChange` method.

Comment: You could implement FileAlterationListenerImpl so that it ignores onFileCreate() calls where the last file processed was "less than n seconds ago". Have a "long lastFileProcessedAt" and set to "Long.MIN_VALUE" (so the first notification fires). Then, when onFileCreate is called - if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastFileProcessedAt < THRESHOLD), return. Remember, set lastFileProcessedAt to System.currentTimeMillis() when you DO process the file. *Just seen this is per "provider" so maybe a Map<String, Long> where key = provider. If this is a workable solution I'll provide code in an answer!

Comment: @NotaJD - I had actually considered something pretty similar to this but wasn't really sure how to go about implementing it properly. You solution definitely sounds workable and I would very much appreciate seeing how you would go about it.

Comment: @SojitJoshi I had also considered doing that as well and actually implemented a version of that. But for some reason the file server we use doesn't update timestamps of "parent" folders when a "child' folder is altered so it didn't work the way I had hoped that it would.

Comment: @ThomasHoppenreys sure - waiting on a production release to finsih right now, so had a quick go. See below!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and crude implementation:

```
public class FileAlterationListenerAlterThrottler {
    private static final int DEFAULT_THRESHOLD_MS = 5000;

    private final int thresholdMs;
    private final Map<String, Long> providerLastFileProcessedAt = new HashMap<>();

    public FileAlterationListenerAlterThrottler() {
        this(DEFAULT_THRESHOLD_MS);
    }

    public FileAlterationListenerAlterThrottler(int thresholdMs) {
        this.thresholdMs = thresholdMs;
    }

    public synchronized boolean shouldAlertFor(String provider) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long last = providerLastFileProcessedAt.computeIfAbsent(provider, x -> 0l);

        if (now - last < thresholdMs) {
            return false;
        }

        providerLastFileProcessedAt.put(provider, now);

        return true;
    }

}
```

And a quicker and cruder driver:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int myThreshold = 1000;

        FileAlterationListenerAlterThrottler throttler = new FileAlterationListenerAlterThrottler(myThreshold);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            doIt(throttler);
        }

        Thread.sleep(1500);

        doIt(throttler);
    }

    private static void doIt(FileAlterationListenerAlterThrottler throttler) {
        boolean shouldAlert = throttler.shouldAlertFor("Some Provider");

        System.out.println("Time now: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println("Should alert? " + shouldAlert);

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Yields:

```
Time now: 1553739126557
Should alert? true

Time now: 1553739126557
Should alert? false

Time now: 1553739126557
Should alert? false

Time now: 1553739128058
Should alert? true
```

Comment: Nice, that looks like something I can make work and think I follow it all. The files just kinda come flooding in when we get them so I'll probably have to play with the threshold and see what kind of alerts I get. That definitely helps get me where I want to go so thanks a lot! I appreciate it.